# Authentication middleware blocks OPTIONS preflight request due to custom header absence

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, proxy, http-proxy

I have a React application using `axios` as HTTP library, `express` server that uses `http-proxy-middleware` package and API `express` server that contains APIs.

React application should communicate with API server through proxy authentication server like this:

[image: Communication between client and API server goes through proxy server]

Within my React application I created this test method:

```
testReq(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/applicationData/checkMe', {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'x-access-token': '...'
      }
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response.status))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
```

This is how my proxy method looks like:

```
server.use('/applicationData', authenticate, proxy({
    target: 'http://localhost:4000',
    changeOrigin: false,
    onProxyReq(proxyReq, req) {
      // proxyReq.setHeader('x-access-identity-email', req.decodedToken.email)
    },
  }))
```

and this is `authenticate` middleware function used above:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers['x-access-token']
  console.log('token', token)
  if (token) {
    verifyToken(token, global.config.secret).then((verificationResponse) => {
      const { decoded, message } = verificationResponse
      if (!decoded) return res.status(401).json({ message })
      req.decoded = decoded
      return next()
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal error' })
    })
  } else return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Missing authentication token' })
}
```

I enabled CORS on both API and Proxy servers like this:

```
server.all('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    next()
  })
```

The problem is that I get this response when request is sent:

[image]

I assume it's due to authentication middleware trying to access `x-access-token` header from `OPTIONS` request which doesn't exist and therefore returns 401. If I remove `authentication` middleware from proxy method then requests go through.

How do I make `x-access-token` present in `OPTIONS` requests? Or else, what is the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: change it to `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'`

Comment: @zabusa I think that is not related. Please read last part of question. On this suggestion of yours: when I do that I get another error. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'localhost:3000'; is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in facebook not allowing to paste code not sure, why, so pasting here:

in your middleware missing is (for options part as you have commented):

```
if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
  res.send(200);
}
else {
  next();
}
```

for error part, as you have said authentication triggering before cors part, so you may have to set that code before authentication (security part I am not much sure)

Comment: Can anybody confirm that this approach is secure?

Answer (score 0):

I think the line:

```
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token')
```

should be:

```
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: That looks like a repetition of the key "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", probably the server is not parsing that line correctly

Comment: Yeah might need to fix this but that's not related to problem at hand (please read last part of question). I done a bit more googleing, turns of the only solution I could find is one mentioned in answer above, but it smells unsecure...

Comment: Well, before using the solution above  I'd make sure that the server is working correctly: if x-access-token is not allowed the OPTIONS request will probably be rejected

Comment: The thing about OPTIONS request is that it removes all custom headers from itself. (afaik)